# c# How to add data from a file to array using streamreader and print it out with a calculation?

Tags: c#

I have my following code to read values from csv file and do some processing. The point is to process and print out the data until each loan reaches zero. I specifically need it to print out as per below:

CSV files data:

> 20000,0.003,2000
>   41000,0.0025,2200

Month 1:

Car Loan 1:
Remaining Balance: $xxxxx
Payment to Principal: $xxxxx
Payment to Interest: $xxxxx

Car Loan 2:
Remaining Balance: $xxxxx
Payment to Principal: $xxxxx
Payment to Interest: $xxxxx

Month 2...

ETC...until remaining balance is zero.

Currently I can only get it to output Car Loan 1's data until Remaining Balance hits zero and then it starts outputting Car Loan 2's data.

My Code:

```
CarLoan[] objCarLoan = new CarLoan[3];

    public static void LoadData(ref CarLoan[] objCarLoan, string filePath)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        for (int i = 1; i < objCarLoan.Length; i++)
        {
            objCarLoan[i] = new CarLoan();
            objCarLoan[i].startingTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.ReadLine().Replace(',', '\n'));
            objCarLoan[i].monthlyInterest = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.ReadLine().Replace(',', '\n'));
            objCarLoan[i].monthlyPayment = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.ReadLine().Replace(',', '\n'));
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    public void CarLoanCalculations()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("\t Remaining Balance: " + (startingTotal - monthlyPayment));
        while (startingTotal > 0)
        {
            if (startingTotal >= 0)
            {
                startingTotal -= monthlyPayment;
                Console.WriteLine("Remaining Balance: " + startingTotal.ToString("C"));
                Console.WriteLine("Payment to Principal: " + paymentToPrincipal.ToString("C"));
                Console.WriteLine("Payment to Interest: " + paymentToInterest.ToString("C"));
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Balance: 0");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DisplayMonthlyPayments(CarLoan[] objCarLoan)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < objCarLoan.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Car Loan" + i);
            objCarLoan[i].CarLoanCalculations();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain more, Using your data sample, what is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

you are reading the line more then once you should read a line and then split it then you can use
ex -

```
objCarLoan[i] = new CarLoan();
string[] line = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
objCarLoan[i].startingTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(line[0]);
objCarLoan[i].monthlyInterest = Convert.ToDecimal(line[1]);
objCarLoan[i].monthlyPayment = Convert.ToDecimal(line[2]);
```

try this and tell me if its working

Comment: I'm getting an unhandled exception now with your code. The reason why I used Convert.ToDecimal(reader.ReadLine().Replace(',', '\n')); was to split the data onto a new line so both sets of data could be read into my fields, for some reason I kept running into a problem doing it your way.

Comment: while debugging have you  checked the data inside string[] line

Comment: if i set the breakpoint at  objMortgage[i].startingTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(line[0]); it shows 20000

Comment: isnt that what you needed ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't thorough with that. At objMortgage[i].monthlyPayment = Convert.ToDecimal(line[2]); ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: and why you are starting your loop from 1 istead of 0

Comment: CSV files data:

20000,0.003,2000<br>
41000,0.0025,2200

Comment: have you putted the <br> tag in the message ?

Comment: sorry that was just to specify they are on different lines in the csv